# Create Windows installer to copy batch files and create shortcut keys for them

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, inno-setup, nsis

I have a set of 3 batch files that I want installed on the user's system. I want to create an installer that shall -

1. Copy these batch files to a folder specified by the user during installation process.
2. Create keyboard shortcuts to each of these batch files.
3. Optionally allow the user to choose these keyboard Shortcuts during installation.
4. Create an uninstaller for all of these.

I tried several installers like Inno Setup, NSIS but couldn't find the functionality of creating keyboard shortcuts.

Anyone know of any means to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I've never even **heard** of installers that used keyboard shortcuts. what did you want them to do? What amount of interactivity were you planning beyond "click the 'Next' button a lot?"

Comment: @SomethingDark I think you read it wrong. I want to create keyboard shortcuts for the batch files that the installer will install/copy so that these batch files can be executed from anywhere in windows.

Comment: You should add that to your question. In order to run a file from anywhere, add the folder it is in to the PATH variable.

Comment: You've got the `HotKey` parameter in the `[Icons]` section in Inno Setup. I believe it will be possible to *fill* this value from `[Code]` from some input edit box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create shortcuts assigning the hotkeys. In NSIS you can do it with the [CreateShortCut](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#createshortcut) instruction.

Example from the documentation:

```
CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\My Company"
CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\My Company\My Program.lnk" "$INSTDIR\My Program.exe" \
  "some command line parameters" "$INSTDIR\My Program.exe" 2 SW_SHOWNORMAL \
  ALT|CONTROL|SHIFT|F5 "a description"
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection
And therin the section **HotKey**.

What you can do is, create an extra Page and allow the user therin to define some shortcuts and then assign them to a variable which you return via a function.

which would look in the end something like

```
Hotkey: {code:GetHotkey}
```

Comment: You cannot use `{code:}` constant for the `Hotkey` parameter (it must be known [`at compilation time`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Compile.pas#L5020)). So I was wrong with my belief. But you can still create shortcuts by using `IShellLinkW` interface purely in `[Code]` section. What will be worse is sanitizing and translating the edit text to shortcut value (but that's the problem related to NSIS as well, unless they have a built-in support e.g. for [`hotkey controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).